# Trig question, can this be solved?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

I was wondering is it possible to solve this without assuming that CAD=DAB. As I use the law of sines, trigonometry and have tried to apply law of cosines. However, I cannot see how you can solve this with just using a and $\alpha$.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see figure properly. I guess the answer is no, as we can change $AD$ freely within $\alpha $ and yet construct a right angled triangle to fit it

Comment: Extend $CA$ a little, to $CA'$. Extend $CB$ a little, to $CB'$, so that $A'B'$ is parallel to $AB$. Then we can find $D'$ in $AD$ such that $A'D'=AD=a$. The shaded area has increased. Your picture was very helpful.

Comment: Yes indeed, the question was well expressed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if $a$ and $\alpha$ alone uniquely define the triangle? If so, the answer is no.

To see this, draw the point $A$ and two lines from $A$ that make an angle $\alpha$. Then draw a line of length $a$ 'inside' this angle, and then draw $CB$ appropriately. This gives a range of triangles from $|AB| = a$, $|AC| = a \cos \alpha$ to $|AC| = a$, $|AB| = \frac{1}{\cos \alpha} a$.

Comment: I'm asking can you express AC in terms of $a$ and $\alpha$ only.

Comment: That's what copper hat assumes too, and negates ($A$ in 1st paragraph is a typo, he means $a$.

Comment: @gnometorule: Thanks for catching that, my typing skills are  poor.